# how to insert record in DB using unix scritpting

Tags: oracle, unix

How should i insert record in the oracle Database with the help of Unix scripting. What are the variables we have to set ? Could you please provide some solution for this .

Answer (score 2):

YOur question is pretty vague, but overall, you invoke sqlplus and either pass it the name of a sql script, like this:

```
sqlplus username/pswd @myscript.sql
```

or supply the sql statement by way of input redirection:

```
sqlplus username/pswd << EOF
insert into mytable values ('A','B','C').
EOF
```

With input redirection you can supply run-time values via enviornment variables.

```
sqlplus usename/pwd << EOF
insert into mytable values ($var1, $var2)
EOF
```

With the sqlscript, you can write it to accept run-time input as command line options, that are themselves supplied by environment variables.

```
sqlplus username/pswd @myscript.sql $var1 $var2
```